# How to show only total file size of particular extension in MB GB OR KB in solaris KSH Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris, ksh

How to show only total file size of particular extension in MB GB OR KB in sun solaris KSH Shell script I have tried AWK command, below is command:-

```
BACKUP_SIZE=`find $EXPDP_DIR_PATH -name "DotNet_LI_TRADES_pre_release_*_12092017.log" -exec ls -ltr {} \; | awk ' BEGIN{split("B KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB",v)} {s+=$5} {s=1;while($5>1024&&s<9){$5/=1024;s++}  printf "%6.2f %s\n",$5,v[s],$9}'`
```

**Output:-**

echo $BACKUP_SIZE

```
681.02 MB 682.54 MB 552.33 MB 1.77 GB 5.92 GB 374.07 MB
```

**Desired Output:-**

```
66.87 GB
```

Comment: Don't use `find ... ls -ltr`. Use `du -sh PATH_TO_BACKUPS` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your output should be around `9.9 GB` seems to be typo. If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same too.

```
BACKUP_SIZE="681.02 MB 682.54 MB 552.33 MB 1.77 GB 5.92 GB 374.07 MB"
echo $BACKUP_SIZE | 
  nawk '{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
      if ($i=="MB") {
        val=val?val+$(i-1)*.001 : $(i-1)*.001
      } else {
        val=val?val+$(i-1) : $(i-1)
      }
    }
  }
  END { print val }'
```

Since you have added Solaris on this question so adding here: on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`, or `nawk`

***EDIT:*** As OP needs to get answer in 2 floating point so following may help you in same.

```
echo $BACKUP_SIZE |
  nawk '{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
      if ($i=="MB") {
        val=val?val+$(i-1)*.001 : $(i-1)*.001
      } else {
        val=val?val+$(i-1) : $(i-1)
      }
    }
  }
  END { 
    printf("%.02f %s\n", val, "GB" )
  }'
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder after running above command i got output as:

`awk: syntax error near line 4
awk: illegal statement near line 4
awk: syntax error near line 7
awk: illegal statement near line 7`

Comment: as per your suggestion i use the same /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk but still getting same error i am on SUN solaris

Comment: @Abhinav, did you check with `nawk` too?

Comment: its working but i am getting it as 9.97996 output and i want output as 9.98GB also can we integrate with this my find command